# AlarmManager broadcasting at random times

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am developing an android app and have an operation that occurs repeatedly, even when the app is closed. I use android's `AlarmManager` to schedule the repeated event as follows:

Broadcast Receiver code (relevant part):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    this.lastContext = context;
    Log.i("Instructions", "Getting instructions...");
    Session.device = (Device)intent.getExtras().get("device");
    Session.user = (User)intent.getExtras().get("user");
    Session.data = (Data)intent.getExtras().get("data");
    Session.deviceManager = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    Session.compAdmin = new ComponentName(context, ControlAdmin.class);
    new ApiRequest(Api.makeDeviceRequest("instruction.php")).builder()
    .addOption("username", Session.user.getUsername())
    .addOption("password", Session.user.getPassword())
    .addOption("device_id", Session.device.getNetId())
    .setCallback(this)
    .execute();
}
```

The above code simply sends a GET request to an online API to download a string which contains some information for the device.

This is how I register the broadcast receiver with the AlarmManager:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 48432;

public static void register(Context context, Class<? extends BroadcastReceiver> receiver, long delay, long interval, String[] keys, Parcelable[] objects){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, receiver);
    if(keys != null && objects != null)
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length && i < objects.length; i++)
            intent.putExtra(keys[i], objects[i]);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

    long firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + delay;

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, interval, sender);
}
```

How I use the register method above:

```
register(context, InstructionsReceiver.class, 0L, 5000L, new String[] { "user", "device", "data" }, new Parcelable[] { Session.user, Session.device, Session.data });
```

The broadcast receiver **does** receive broadcasts but not at 5 second intervals as I have written in the example above. Instead, the intervals are random above 60 seconds. I don't understand why this is happening.

Is this normal (says irregular intervals in AlarmManager [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) > API 19)? If not, what have I done wrong?

Comment: As reported in the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html): `Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.`

Comment: I'll experiment with setWindow and setExact and get back to you - thanks for the reply.

Comment: No... The solution is: `Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.` In other words, you have to use `setExact()` (non repeating) and re-schedule it after firing. For **older** (< 19) API Levels, simply use `setRepeating()`.

Comment: But I guess the same gear works on older versions too. So, no need to check the API Level. Just use `setExact()` + reschedule

Comment: The setWindow method is only available on API > 19 so I'll need to do a check for that. Thanks again. @FrankN.Stein

Comment: See also [this pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/GdNrQciPwqo)